# Is it possible to use all Magento 2's functionality through its REST API?

Tags: rest, magento2

The last time I worked with Magento 1.x there wasn't a good REST API in place.

Now there looks to be one: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html

I would like to integrate the Magento checkout and catalog (from a consumer perspective if you will) completely through the REST API (including the cart, stores etcetera).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 came up with vast features of REST API.So many Default REST API's are provided to manage the all customer activities,customer address management,CMS management

To know more core API

```
MAGENTO(ROOT FOLDER)/vendor/magento/magento-customer/etc/webapi.xml
```

Even we can create our own custom REST API to manage any other core activity by loading the model(db table)